# Page height is not 100% (some space at the bottom)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

All the pages/tabs height is 100%  but in this one when the zoom is less than 100% there some space at the bottom of the page.. (at all other pages there no space)
All the styles fixed to 100% height and no margins ...
can't really understand what could be a reason for that..

**working with wordpress with the woocomerce theme..

[image: 100% Zoom]
[image: 75% Zoom with space at the bottom]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily fixed by adding:

```
html { min-height:100%; }
```

This tells the page that **it cannot be less than 100%** and should expand to the rest of the page. Any other problems must be browser-specific that may not affect everyone.

Comment: tnx but it's doesn't helps :( i am dispaired

Comment: finally fixed it with...  inline style for the div that should be at the bottom of the page...  position:fixed;   bottom:0 ; height: calc(100% - 255px);